# Ошибка в paginator django в пагинаторе на heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

ProgrammingError at /blog/
relation "nyastul_post" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "nyastul_post" 
все команды работают 
миграции сделал
не понимаю даже суть ошибки на локальном хост посте все отлично работает
вот это вылетает из за

[image: вот ошибка]
[image: вот из за этого]

page = paginator.get_page(page_number)

```
`from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import View

from .models import Post, Tag
from .utils import *
from .forms import TagForm, PostForm

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.db.models import Q
# Create your views here.
def posts_list(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('search', '')

    if search_query:
        posts = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_query) | Q(body__icontains=search_query))
    else:
        posts = Post.objects.all()

    posts = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 3)



    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    page = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    is_paginated = page.has_other_pages()

    if page.has_previous():
        prev_url = '?page={}'.format(page.previous_page_number())
    else:
        prev_url = ''
    if page.has_next():
        next_url = '?page={}'.format(page.next_page_number())
    else:
        next_url = ''

    context = {
        'page_object': page,
        'is_paginated': is_paginated,
        'next_url': next_url,
        'prev_url': prev_url
}

    return render(request, 'nyastul/index.html', context=context)
```

`

Comment: `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: пробовал и команда прошла